# Отправка сообщений нескольким клиентам от сервера, java

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокеты

есть сервер чата, который должен получать строку и отправлять её значение всем подключённым клиентам (каждый клиент находится в отдельном потоке), но отправляет только тому клиенту который строку эту и отправил, другие клиенты этого сообщения не видят. Я вроде понимаю что надо как-то передавать значение между потоками, но как это сделать я хз, подскажите пожалуйста!

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
Socket clientSocket;
MyThread(Socket a) 
{ 
    clientSocket = a; 
}
@Override
public void run()
{
    String remoteIp = clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
     System.out.println("Got a connection from: " + remoteIp);
     System.out.println();
    try {
            // Берем входной и выходной потоки сокета, теперь можем получать и отсылать данные клиенту. 
     InputStream sin = clientSocket.getInputStream();
     OutputStream sout = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

            // Конвертируем потоки в другой тип, чтоб легче обрабатывать текстовые сообщения.
     DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
     DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

     String line = null;
     while(true) {
       line = in.readUTF(); // ожидаем пока клиент пришлет строку текста.
       System.out.println(line);
       out.writeUTF(line); // отсылаем клиенту строку текста.
       out.flush(); // заставляем поток закончить передачу данных.
     }
    } catch(Exception x) {}
}
```

и откуда этот поток запускаю

```
public class Server {
 public static void main(String[] ar) throws IOException {
  ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(13372);
    while (true)
    {
     System.out.println("Waiting for a connection..");
     Socket NewSocket = ss.accept();
     MyThread NewClient = new MyThread(NewSocket);
     NewClient.start();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Не наследуйтесь от thread, это еще выстрелит в ногу. Используйте ThreadPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы сервер рассылал сообщения всем клиентам, у него должен быть список всех connection'ов клиентов (т.е. при подключении нового клиента кладем его сокет-класс-поток в этот список). Далее, когда серверу что-то приходит, просто через for перебирается весь список и каждому клиенту отправляется сообщение.

Comment: сижу, уже час думаю как вашу идею реализовать, не подскажите код для этого?

Comment: @ZecosMAX http://www.quizful.net/post/base_network_in_java